# Como alterar 'policy' para pública de apenas um file no minio.io

Tags: javascript

Estou rodando local o minio.io através do docker.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura.

Bucket: private

path: private/contrato/

arquivos:

- contrato1.jpeg
- contrato2.jpeg

path individual: private/contrato/contrato1.jpeg

Preciso disponibilizar dentro da pasta contrato, apenas o contrato1.jpeg para donwload. Os outros arquivos devem continuar sendo mantidos como private.

Estou usando a sdk para linguagem javascript. Tentei alterar a policy apenas do arquivo, porém só consegui alterar a 'policy' da pasta toda.

O link para documentação do [minio](https://docs.minio.io/)